# HorizontalScrollView, auto-scroll to end with animation

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontalScrollView and I need to make an auto-scroll to end with animation when I load the view. I have implemented this method to do it:

```
final HorizontalScrollView strip = (HorizontalScrollView) contentView.
    findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);

strip.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        strip.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
    }
}, 1000L);
```

It works fine, but, the main problem is the animation of the scrolling is too fast and I need to implement a slower scrolling. Have you any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a demo project I created for one of my projects. Its a scroller the scroll automatically and continously. It was made to show a credits screen by continously scrolling through a list of images.
This might help you or give you some idea.

https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
ObjectAnimator animator=ObjectAnimator.ofInt(buttonHolderScrollView, "scrollX",targetXScroll );
animator.setStartDelay(100);
animator.setDuration(100);
animator.start();
```

Comment: If yout want to scroll to end, use `targetXScroll = horizontalScrollView.right`